# If option value is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want a function to be executed if a specific select option is visible.
I have tried the following code:

```
if ($(("#daychoise option[value='monday2']").is(':visible'))) {

}
```

That didn't work and I got the following error in the console:

Uncaught TypeError: Object #daychoise option[value='monday2'] has no method 'is'

So how do I check if a select option is visible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have extra `()`. Should be `$("#daychoise option[value='monday2']").is(':visible')`. However it's not going to work anyway.

Comment: could you please make a fiddle ? we don't know what exactly you lookin' for

Answer (score 8):

Wrong selector !
You should use this :

```
if ($("#daychoise option[value='monday2']").is(':visible')) {

}
```

Comment: That removed the error. However my code is still not executed even though option value monday2 is visible.

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant this

```
if (($("#daychoise option[value='monday2']").is(':visible'))) {

}
```

Note the location of the `$`

Answer (score 0):

You can hav it like this

```
<select id="selectbox">
<option value="0">sunday</option>
<option value="1">monday</option>
<option value="2">Tuesday</option>
<option value="3">Wednesday</option>
<select>
```

and in jquery you can write as

```
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          if($("#selectbox").val() == 1){
            // do something
          }
        });
      </script>
```

Comment: Yeah, but my code is required to check if multiple options in my select is visible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a value is selected in a multiple selectbox

```
<select multiple>...</select>
```

you should do it this way:

```
if ($.inArray('monday2', $("#daychoise").val()) !== -1) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try:

```
$(("#daychoise option[value='monday2']").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':visible')){
             //do what you want
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

An option element always returns false when its status is tested with the :visible selector, as the element doesn't occupy space in the DOM. If you hide the option element with hide(), you can instead retrieve the CSS value for the display property:

```
$('#daychoise option[value="monday2"]').hide();

if($('#daychoise option[value="monday2"]').css('display') == 'none')
{
    alert('monday2 is hidden');
}
else
{
    alert('monday2 is visible');
}
```